# List compiles, but gives warning: incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, struct, declaration, typedef, incompatibletypeerror

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int number;
    struct player *next;
}player;

player *newPlayer;
player *firstPlayer;
player *currentPlayer;

int main(void)
{
    newPlayer = malloc(sizeof(player));
    firstPlayer = newPlayer;
    currentPlayer = newPlayer;
    currentPlayer->next = NULL;
    printf("Please enter Head: ");
    scanf("%d", &currentPlayer->number);

    newPlayer = malloc(sizeof(player));
    currentPlayer->next = newPlayer;
    currentPlayer = newPlayer;
    currentPlayer->next = NULL;
    printf("Please enter second element: ");
    scanf("%d", &currentPlayer->number);


    currentPlayer = firstPlayer;
    while (currentPlayer)
    {
        printf("%d ", currentPlayer->number);
        currentPlayer = currentPlayer->next;
    }
    printf("\n");


}
```

The code compiles correctly, but I get these warnings:
warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
`currentPlayer->next = newPlayer;`
and
warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
`currentPlayer = currentPlayer->next;`
Why is that and how can I fix it?
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate; the problem, as ever, is finding what it's a duplicate of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining your struct, you omitted the struct name. By doing that, you actually created a *generic* struct, which can be referred to only by its typedef (alias).

```
typedef struct
{
    int number;
    struct player *next;
} player;
```

In this definition, player is just an alias to this generic struct.

To fix that, add the word player to the first line:

```
typedef struct player
{
    int number;
    struct player *next;
} player_t;
```

Now, you're able to refer the struct either by `struct player`, or by `player_t`.

Always remember that the keyword `typedef` is just for us, the programmers, for readability. Don't count on it to do some extra work.

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, it's possible to use `typedef struct player player` and refer to the struct either by `struct player` or just plain `player`.

Comment: But what exactly is the `player` and the `player_t` ?

Comment: In this context, _player_ by itself has no meaning. You may refer to you struct in 2 ways: **player_t**, or **struct player**.

Comment: Note that the structure tag (`struct player`) is in a separate namespace from the typedef name, so it is safe to use `typedef struct player player;` (with or without the defining `{ … }` structure definition in the statement).  Also, the `_t` suffix is reserved by POSIX — be cautious about using your own type names ending `_t`.  You'll get away with it 99.9% of the time.  Then it'll come back and bite you on some system you hadn't encountered before.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You're absolutely right, I changed it just to prevent a confusion in this context. I should clear it up.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but how would I define a `typedef struct player player`?

Comment: Exactly the way you did in your question. You just need to add to the first line of the definition the word player: typedef struct player.

Comment: @N00b: You could write `typedef struct player player;` like that, and then add `struct player { int number; player *next; };` to define the contents of the structure.  Or, if you don't need to allocate the structure (allocating pointers is sufficient) and don't need to access the insides, you could use just the `typedef` line.  Or you can do `typedef struct player { int number; struct player *next; } player;`, noting that the typedef name `player` isn't defined until the semicolon at the end, so must use `struct player` and not just `player` within the structure.

Answer (score 2):

In this typedef declaration

```
typedef struct
{
    int number;
    struct player *next;
}player;
```

there are declared two types. The first one is an unnamed structure that is given the typedef name `player`.

```
typedef struct
{
    //...
}player;
```

The second type is incomplete type `struct player` declared in the unnamed structure definition.

```
    struct player *next;
```

The pointer types `struct player *` and `player *` are two different types that are not compatible.

So for a statement like for example this

```
currentPlayer->next = newPlayer;
```

the compiler will issue an error because in the left side hand there is an object of the type `struct player *` while in the right side hand there is an object of the type `player *`.

You should write

```
typedef struct player
{
    int number;
    struct player *next;
}player;
```

Pay attention to that there is no any need to define these pointers in the file scope

```
player *newPlayer;
player *firstPlayer;
player *currentPlayer;
```

Each variable should be declared in the smallest scope where it is used. So these pointers could be declared within the function main.